# If Mdb file is created for MSAccess then what file is created for Informix what is the path for it

Tags: informix

If Mdb file is created for MSAccess then what file is created for Informix , and what is the path for it

Comment: How would an MS-Access MDB file influence an Informix database?

Comment: Its not influence. I understand these are two different things. But what is the database file created for Infromix.the name of extension.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do with that?

Most databases I know do not work with only one file which can be easily copied between machines. For Informix there is `ROOTPATH` parameter in `ONCONFIG` file which points to initial chunk of root dbspace. If it sounds strange then you should read more about Informix architecture and Informix administration.

If all you want is to copy database than you can use `dbexport DATABASE_NAME` which will create directory with SQL (schema) and text data files. Those files can be imported with `dbimport DATABASE_NAME`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no database "file" like MS Access or SQLite, which are server-less databases, for Informix databases.

Accessing data from an Informix database requires some sort connection with the database server. Search for Informix drivers for more info.

If you're interested, I know from experience that you can connect to an Informix server using MS Access via an ODBC driver.  This would give you a familiar interface in MS Access while directly working with Informix data.

If you are able to do some light programming, I would similarly suggest setting up Informix for ODBC, then connect to the database using an ODBC driver in chosen language.  I have done this using Go, Python, and R.